# PHP - "pretty" print key-value of large, unknown, multi-dimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a (painless?) way to echo or otherwise log a large, multidimensional array when I don't know if a given value will be an array, or if those values will be arrays, etc. etc. forever. It could be ten or fifteen levels deep, with string and / or array values and manually nesting foreach loops seems inefficient and wrong.

var_dump is too verbose and too difficult to decipher for my purposes.

Thoughts?

Comment: Probably something recursive, maybe array_map though also could be used. A recursive approach https://3v4l.org/uFp7B

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function pre(...$vars) {
    if (!is_array($vars)) {
        $vars = [$vars];
    }
    
    print('<pre>');
    
    foreach ($vars as $var) {
        print_r($var);
        print("\n");
    }
    
    print('</pre>');
    print("\n");
    
    ob_flush();
}
```

**Example**

```
\pre($array);
\pre($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can save var_dump output in log file.

Please refer https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/writing-to-the-php-error_log-with-var_dump-and-print_r/

Answer (score 0):

You can display your array as JSON. With appropriate headers, your browser is able to display it nicely (search, collapsing, and more).

```
$largeArray = ['data' => ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'qux']];
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($largeArray);
exit;
```